# MySQL concat just a portion of statement

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I know how to concatenate all the columns, but I struggle to concatenate just a portion of it. SQL now looks like this:

```
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM db WHERE id = 1
```

I want to CONCAT fields col3 and col4. Have tried several approaches, but nothing seems to work, like this one

```
    SELECT col1, col2, CONCAT(col3, col4), col5 FROM db WHERE id = 1
```

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

As it turns out, it CAN be accomplished this way. Don't know what I did wrong. Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: I would expect your statement to work except where 1 of the columns is null. Do you have an example where it doesn't?

Comment: Or even an error message? How are you looking at the result> Are you using PHP or some code to view the result or something like phpMyAdmin

Comment: what's the problem with your query ?  show a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: why your table name is missing and you can try like `col3+''+col4 as columnname`

Comment: I'm using this for JQuery DataTables and all works fine until I add the CONCAT, that's why I thought the statement was wrong. I'm using PHP and write the result to json_encode, don't get an error message, the result just dissapears. Forgot about using phpmyadmin, that would probably give me an error message. I was looking all over the place for the right syntax, and if this is right (except for the table name) I'm pretty good to go. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Then try adding an alias like this so the result column has an easily accessible name `SELECT col1, col2, CONCAT(col3, col4) as concat_col, col5 FROM db WHERE id = 1` I had a feeling that was going to be the problem right from the start

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not `concat()`, You missed  `from` clause

```
SELECT col1, col2, CONCAT(col3, col4), col5 
FROM my_table
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: I forgot the FROM clause in the example, my bad. But that's not the problem. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: With this sintax the query part must work .. but you should update you question adding you  related code  .. could be that the problem is not the query but the context where the query is executed .

Answer (score 0):

Use CONCAT_WS instead CONCAT. the first argument ist then the separator.

**sample**

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT_WS('',NULL,'Hello',' ','world');
```

**result**

```
Hello world
```